# Angular 2 NgFor Pattern Error Message Not Showing

Tags: javascript, regex, html, angular

I'm trying to have inputs with a regex requirement in a ngFor loop but am not seeing the error message as expected when I put something that doesn't match the required pattern.

"Test" is never hidden and `<div *ngIf="id?.hasError('pattern')">` never shows, even when I enter the wrong pattern. I can see that the input fails because I'm using Material Design and the color of the line underlining the input changes to red but I do not see any changes in regards to the error messages.

Here is my code at the moment:

(The keys pipe I have is a custom pipe because item is an object made of objects, so that breaks down the contained objects into key/value pairs.)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | keys">

  <md-input-container>
    <input
      mdInput
      placeholder={{item.placeholder}}
      name={{item.name}}
      pattern="\d{7}"
      [(ngModel)]="item.currentValue"
      #id="ngModel"
    >
  </md-input-container>

  <div
    [hidden]="id?.valid || id?.pristine"
  >
    <p>Test</p>
    <div *ngIf="id?.hasError('pattern')">
      Pattern should be xxxxxxx 
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have already told you your pattern is wrong. If you need to match a 7 digit string, just use `"\d{7}"`. Or if it can be empty `"(?:\d{7})?"`. `[\d{7}]*` matches 0 or more chars that are a digit, `{`, `7` or `}`.

Comment: I appreciate the heads up, even after changing the pattern to "\d{7}" I'm still having the same issue with the messages not being hidden/displayed when the input fails validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing `name={{item.name}}` to `name="id"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in next way:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | keys">

<md-input-container>
<input
  mdInput
  placeholder={{item.placeholder}}
  name={{item.name}}
  pattern="\d{7}"
  [(ngModel)]="item.currentValue"
  #id="ngModel"
>
</md-input-container>

<div [hidden]="!displayValid(id)">
<p>Test</p>        
      Pattern should be xxxxxxx 
</div>
</div>
```

And this fun in .ts file of component:

```
 displayValid(inputRef: any): boolean {
        let errors: any = inputRef.errors;

        return errors && errors.pattern;
 }
```